# Creating Views in entity framework

Tags: .net, database, frameworks, c#-4.0, entity

we are using entity framework, but generating the database from the edmx file not generating the edmx file from the database. I've used views with the framework, but only when generating the edmx file from the database. There doesn't seem to be a way to create a view in the model and then push it to the database. Maybe I'm missing something. Views are so useful that I can't imagine there isn't some way to create them in the model then do a "Generate database from model..."

thanks, Mike

Comment: I understand that you have issues in generating strongly typed views. Did you try after building your application once. The Classes for the strongly typed views are taken from the assembly once it is being built.